# Why does After Effects sometimes have an import dialog and sometimes don't?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-after-effects

I'm trying to import illustrator .ai file to After Effects, sometimes I get a dialog within After Effects asking me how I want to import the file. But sometimes the dialog won't show up, and it will directly import the .ai file. I'm wondering why this is happening? And I would prefer to go though this dialog every time.  [image: Import Dialog]

Answer (score 1):

When there are several layers (Release in layers) in .ai file, it will normally show the dialog

When there is a single layer and inside that layer are all the graphics, it will just import as a single file.

Here is the answer to your next question:
"How to properly export/import from Illustrator to After effects"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2Uwdr2M53M

Answer (score 0):

Also there is another possible reason: if your Adobe Illustrator file already has several layers, you may need to save it with PDF settings[image]